# Get-ADUser doesn't return value

Tags: powershell

```
$lastname = Read-Host "Type a surname"
echo $lastname
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*$lastname"' -Properties “LastLogonDate”, “passwordlastset”, "whenCreated"| FT Name,SamAccountName, Lastlogondate, passwordlastset, whenCreated -A
```

When I run the code above it doesn't return anything but when I replace $lastname with a name in my AD it returns the information as it should. What do I do wrong because I don't get it. The echo shows me that the $lastname variable is set after I type the surname in the prompt.

Comment: try to put an additional asterisk (*) after the lastname ... like this `"*$lastname*"`

Comment: Still doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ah ... stupid me ... you have to put `-Filter 'SurName -like "*$lastname*"'`

Comment: Still doesn't return anything, like it skips the whole Get-ADUser or something

Comment: I need new glasses ...  ;-)  `-Filter "SurName -like '*$lastname*'"`  ... the quoting was wrong. The double quotes belong "outside"

Comment: Now it runs perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: As sidenote, remove the curly quotes around the properties. As number1 rule: **never** use these so-called 'smart-quotes' in code.